# Excel Power Query Import XML filtering by node name

Tags: excel, xml, powerquery

I'm trying to import data from a website into Excel.

My sample data looks like this:

```
<WebbyServer>
    <Agency>ABC123</Agency>
    <Site Name="Sandy Bay Nth Lagoon"> </Site>
    <Site Name="Muddy River at ClipClop Bridge"> </Site>
    <Site Name="Fishy Beach at Yacht Club "> </Site>    
</WebbyServer>
```

The XML nodes for Sites are singletons. I want to import the site names into an Excel Table. (So I want to skip the "Agency" node or filter by "Site"?).

My code looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("E:\Temp\data.xml")),
    SiteTable = Source{[Site="Site Name"]}[Table]
in
    SiteTable
```

I'd like the data loaded into an excel sheet/table, that would look like:

```
+--------------------------------+
|              Name              |
+--------------------------------+
| Sandy Bay Nth Lagoon           |
| Muddy River at ClipClop Bridge |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club      |
+--------------------------------+
```

How do I:

1. Filter by node?
2. Extract text from a singleton?

Edit: The example I have used is a simple use case, it literally only has 2 node types and the data I want is within the node, the real example just has more rows. I have a more complex XML file to do next but I hoped this would be enough to get me over the first hurdle.

Edit: More complex example below, where I'd want, Site, Datasource, Time and Value:

```
<WebbyServer>
    <Agency>ABC123</Agency>
    <Measurement SiteName="Fishy Beach at Yacht Club">
        <DataSource Name="Enterococci CFU/100ml" NumItems="2">
            <TSType>StdSeries</TSType>
            <DataType>WQData</DataType>
            <Interpolation>Discrete</Interpolation>
            <ItemInfo ItemNumber="1">
            <ItemName>Enterococci CFU/100ml</ItemName>
            <ItemFormat>F</ItemFormat>
            <Units>CFU/100ml</Units>
            <Format/>
            </ItemInfo>
        </DataSource>
        <Data DateFormat="Calendar" NumItems="2">
            <E>
                <T>2015-11-08T08:32:00</T>
                <Value>13</Value>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2015-11-21T08:52:00</T>
                <Value>4.9</Value>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2015-12-08T11:06:00</T>
                <Value><1.6</Value>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2015-12-23T11:34:00</T>
                <Value>5</Value>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2016-01-07T10:22:00</T>
                <Value>1.6</Value>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2016-01-20T10:32:00</T>
                <Value><1.7</Value>
                <Parameter Name="Sample ID" Value="20160360"/>
                <Parameter Name="Received at Lab" Value="21-Jan-2016 08:30"/>
                <Parameter Name="Cost Code" Value="3700012046"/>
                <Parameter Name="Results Received" Value="22-Jan-2016 02:05"/>
                <Parameter Name="Project" Value="SOE Water Quality: Coastal"/>
                <Parameter Name="Archived" Value="10-Mar-2016 11:30"/>
                <Parameter Name="Field Technician" Value="<Not assigned>"/>
            </E>
            <E>
                <T>2016-02-04T09:26:00</T>
                <Value>1.7</Value>
                <Parameter Name="Sample ID" Value="20161317"/>
                <Parameter Name="Cost Code" Value="3700012046"/>
                <Parameter Name="Project" Value="SOE Water Quality: Coastal"/>
                <Parameter Name="Archived" Value="27-Apr-2016 15:33"/>
                <Parameter Name="Field Technician" Value="Billybob"/>
            </E>
        </Data>
    </Measurement>
</WebbyServer>
```

In this case: id want.

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------+
|         SiteName          |      DataSource       |          T          | Value |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml |                     |       |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2015-11-08T08:32:00 | 13    |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2015-11-21T08:52:00 | 4.9   |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2015-12-08T11:06:00 | <1.6  |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2015-12-23T11:34:00 | 5     |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2016-01-07T10:22:00 | 1.6   |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2016-01-20T10:32:00 | <1.7  |
| Fishy Beach at Yacht Club | Enterococci CFU/100ml | 2016-02-04T09:26:00 | 1.7   |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

**Note: the < symbol preceding the values is valid and represent a non-detect in the data

Comment: I think you need to end with </WebbyServer> but beyond that, please explain a bit more.  What does more then one small snippet of data look like. What do you want the output data to look like. A simple expansion here would pull in all the names (sandy,muddy,fishy) which is not what you want because ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sample xml

```
<WebbyServer>
    <Agency>ABC123</Agency>
    <Site Name="Sandy Bay Nth Lagoon"> </Site>
    <Site Name="Muddy River at ClipClop Bridge"> </Site>
    <Site Name="Fishy Beach at Yacht Club "> </Site>    
</WebbyServer>
```

is handled by

```
let  Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Temp\data.xml")),
#"Expanded Site" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Site", {"Attribute:Name"}, {"Attribute:Name"})
in #"Expanded Site"
```

[image]

rename and remove columns as desired

Comment: have I used the correct terminology in my post? could I improve it? Where is the best source for finding the syntax options for the Power Query syntax you used? Cheers.

Comment: In this particular case all you had to do was make a sample file and import it using the graphical interface. At that point you'd see an arrow and if you click that only arrow you get the code above

Comment: Great tip thanks. I'll try that tommorrow. :)

Comment: Code reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference